# Разбить массив объектов на подмассивы JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Господа знатоки помогите с задачей.
Дан массив

```js
let persons = [

    {name : "Mike" , age : 13},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 27},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 30},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 20},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 100},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 80},
    {name : "Nick" , age : 45}
];
```

мне нужно его разбить на подмассивы
на выходе должно получится

```
[{name: 'Mike', age: 13}, {name: 'Mike', age: 30}, {name: 'Mike', age: 80}]

[{name: 'Aron', age: 27}, {name: 'Aron', age: 20}, {name: 'Aron', age: 100}]

[{name : "Nick" , age : 45}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Answer (score 4):

```js
let persons = [{
    name: "Mike",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Aron",
    age: 27
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Aron",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Aron",
    age: 100
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Nick",
    age: 45
  }
];

console.log(
  persons.reduce((a, c) => {
    let idx = a.findIndex(e => e[0].name === c.name);
    if (idx !== -1) a[idx].push(c);
    else a.push([c]);
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант, при больших массивах может быть быстрее за счёт того, что не нужно обыскивать создаваемый массив, но это нужно проверять (промежуточная структура и её преобразование могут скушать память и время, так что выигрыша может и не быть). Ещё одно различие в том, что тут создаются копии элементов, но это может быть и не нужно)

```js
let persons = [
    {name : "Mike" , age : 13},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 27},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 30},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 20},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 100},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 80},
    {name : "Nick" , age : 45}
];


const persons2 = Object.values(persons.reduce(
  (acc, person) => {
    const name = person.name;
    acc[name] ??= [];
    acc[name].push({ ...person });
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(persons2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let persons = [

    {name : "Mike" , age : 13},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 27},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 30},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 20},
    {name : "Aron" , age : 100},
    {name : "Mike" , age : 80},
    {name : "Nick" , age : 45}
];

let result = []
let names = Array.from(new Set(persons.map(el => el.name )))
names.forEach((el, index) =>{
    result[index] = persons.filter(elem => elem.name == el )
})
console.log(result)
```